# Countifs - cell referencing (entire range)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if someone can help me with the following Excel Formula.

I have checked online from various sources and am yet to come across an answer to this.

Essentially I have a very large dataset (10,000 rows +) with around 20 unique clients in the first column. My aim is to filter the database by client and take a count of various different values in another column (in my example 'version' field. So I need a count of different versions for each client.

So far I have written the following countifs formula to achieve this for any given version. Here is an example formula, which I need and will do for the 10 versions that are most interesting to me. FYI I have written this formula on Sheet 2. On sheet 2 I have a list of Versions in column A

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1 (versi'!A:A,"EXAMPLECLIENT",'Sheet1 (Sheet1'!I:I,"=" & A2)
```

I will implement this for the 10 versions I am interested in.

My issue is I would also like to write a formula to identify the number of versions for each client that is not included in my other 10. I know how to achieve this to exlude one of the versions I have listed (as follows) This excludes the referenced cell A2 which I previously looked at in my last formula.

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1 (versi'!A:A,"ABG",'Sheet1 (Sheet1'!I:I,"<>" & A2)
```

I have also been able to achieve this in order to excludes 2 versions on my list on Sheet 2. I used the following formula to achieve this.

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1 (versi'!A:A,"ABG",'Sheet1 (Sheet1'!I:I,"<>" & A2,'Sheet1 (Sheet1'!I:I,"<>" & A3)
```

The problem is I have a list of 10 versions I want to exclude in my count and this ends up being a very long formula.

What I have tried so far is to select the entire range in my formula thinking it would exclude eac each value (see below) but this has not worked as it returns 0 results when I know this isn't true.

```
=COUNTIFS('BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!A:A,"ABG",'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A2,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A2:A12)
```

Comment: It would probably help if you shared some screenshots or sample file.

Comment: I not sure if I understanding correctly, but maybe this formula could do the trick: =COUNTIF('BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!A:A,"ABG") - SUM(A2:A12)

Comment: what about pivot tables?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I am not sure if I can send a sample file yet due to being a new user?.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I tried this formula previously, this was my initial thinking as well but excel provided back values of 0 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comments I ended up adding in further criteria in the `COUNTIFS`. I also excluded some other errors I didn't want to see. My formula now looks like this:

```
=COUNTIFS('BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!A:A,"EXAMPLE CLIENT",'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A2,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A3,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A4,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A5,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A6,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A7,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A8,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A9,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A10,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A11,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A12,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A13,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A14,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A15,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>" & A16,'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>(error: 2)",'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>(inactive)",'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>(no-install)",'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>(unknown: 19)",'BloombergVersionAnalysis (versi'!I:I,"<>")
```

I did find [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xy7Hfo937I) which suggests to use the `MATCH` function. I think this would have worked if I didn't have to specify a client in the large data set first.